# Assigning value to global variable

Tags: delphi, variables, global, assign

I am a beginner to Delphi and am currently practising it in RAD XE5 student version.

I have made 2 units, in the first I specify a variable in the INTERFACE section

like so:

```
interface
var
Globalstring : integer;
```

Then I assign a value to this variable via

```
TextInput.Text = GlobalString
```

Whenever I try to recall globalstring in my second unit, I get a blank.. :(

**08/02/2014**

Okay guys, I am sorry for the lack of information, the frustration had already gotten to me. It was indeed not the real code and the integer was indeed a string all along, so here follows the real code to clear all confusion

```
unit Unit1;

interface
uses FMX.Effects, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Controls,
     System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes,  System.Variants,
     FMX.Types, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Edit, FMX.Filter.Effects, FMX.Objects, Unit2;

type
 TForm1 = class(TForm)
 EditUser: TEdit;
 EditPass: TEdit;
 btnLogin: TButton;
 Label1: TLabel;
 chkGuest: TCheckBox;
 Label2: TLabel;
 SlideTransitionEffect1: TSlideTransitionEffect;
 Image1: TImage;
 procedure btnLoginClick(Sender: TObject);
 procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
private
{ Private declarations }
public

end;

var
 Form1: TForm1;
 UserLogin : string;


implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses Unit4,Unit3,Unit5;

procedure TForm1.btnLoginClick(Sender: TObject);

begin
  Unit2.UsernameJef:= 'Jef'; Unit2.UsernameDennis :='Dennis';
  Unit2.PasswordJef:= '123'; Unit2.PassWordDennis :='456';

if ((EditUser.text=Unit2.UsernameJef) and (EditPass.text=Unit2.PasswordJef))
  or ((EditUser.text=Unit2.UsernameDennis) and (EditPass.text=Unit2.PassWordDennis))
    then form4.Show
      else Label1.Visible := true;



if (EditUser.Text= 'Guest')
  or (chkGuest.IsChecked = true)
   then Form5.Show;

UserLogin := EditUser.Text;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

end.
```

Then here follows the unit 4 in wich I actually use this "global variable".

I want to show a welcoming message in my application after my user logs on, in this case "Welcome Jef" or "Welcome Dennis"

```
procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
lblWelkom.Text := Unit1.UserLogin

end ;

end.
```

Comment: If TextInput.Text is a string and GlobalString is an integer, it would not compile. Please show a complete compilable example.

Comment: The assignment operator is `:=`. And if you want to assign something to 'GlobalString', put it on the left hand side.

Comment: The code you posted would not compile, because the comparison of `TextInput.Text = GlobalString` uses incompatible types (text and integer). If you're having problems with your code, post **your code** and ask a question about the problem. Posting made-up nonsense often hides the actual problem (and results in absolute nonsense like this example). Your poor example also makes no attempt to "assign a value", because a) you're not using the assignment operator, and b) because if you were you would be assigning *from* the `GlobalString` variable, not *to* it.

Comment: Also, if your global variable is an integer, naming it GlobalSTRING is a maintenance nightmare for you in the future, when you forget that it's not really a global **string** but is in fact a global **integer**. Learn now to name your variables accurately, instead of shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Not sure why the particular choice was made on the vote to close (lacking sufficient information to reproduce the issue). Because it has perfect information to reproduce. The problem is that it's an entry-level question.

Comment: @JerryDodge The text of the question contradicts the code provided. The text implies that it ***does*** compile, whereas the code looks like it wouldn't compile. The text goes so far as to state that it produces incorrect behaviour in "second unit". There is no code from the second unit, and nothing to show how the two units interact.

Comment: @KenWhite said: "_uses incompatible types (text and integer)_". If `Globalstring` is declared as an Integer, who's to say `TextInput.Text` isn't also an Integer. :S

Comment: @Jerry This is a canonical *unclear what you are asking* question. The code is fake which is as unclear as can be. It makes no sense in this form. My guess as to the real problem is quite different from your guess. If we all try to answer different questions based on guesswork it's a little pointless. There's a wider aspect. People who ask rubbish questions should get blowback. They should get told, in no uncertain terms, that their questions are deficient. The most important learning for such people is the skill of asking. Once they master that they will learn so much more broadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what you've actually done wrong because you have not posted the necessary code. However, I'll explain some things you seem to be misunderstanding about programming, and perhaps that will help. Otherwise, please update your question with relevant information from both units (we're not all [psychic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21606164/224704)).

Programs execute code as a sequence of instructions. Some instructions call other instructions. And no matter what code may sit inside your first unit that sets a global variable, that variable will not change until the instruction to actually change it has executed.

So, try the following:

- Put a break-point on your line of code in unit 1 that sets the global.
- And another on the line of code that reads the global in unit 2.
- Run your program.
- You will probably find that the program stops at the unit 2 breakpoint **before** the unit 1 breakpoint.
- This means the instruction to change the value **has not executed yet**.
- (And will not execute **until** another line calls the appropriate instruction that will cause it to be executed.)

There are of course other possibilities (but as mentioned before, we need the code in order to debug it):

- There might be **another** instruction somewhere else that that clears the value you previously set.
- Although you made you variable in unit 1 global, you might find that unit 2 is looking at an entirely different value - that happens to have the same name.
- Globals are relatively simple, but if you were using objects you would also have to consider whether both references are using the same instance of your class.
- EDIT: PS: Of course, if you used `=` expecting that to set the value, you'll find it doesn't. `=` is the comparison operator. `:=` is the *assignment* operator; and when using it the result of the expression on the right will be assigned to the variable (global,local,field,argument) on the ***LEFT***.

---

EDIT:

So, if you follow my earlier advice: put a breakpoint on `lblWelkom.Text := Unit1.UserLogin` and another on `UserLogin := EditUser.Text;`. You'll observe that you're reading the value of `UserLogin` **before** you've assigned it. [LU RD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21646114/224704) explains why it's not working, and how to fix it.

Comment: I have a feeling that asker expects the first assignment to set up a two way conduit. So changes to TextInput would flow through the global variable like some magic two way binding conduit. Perhaps. +1 not least for the psychic dig ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One of the fundamental basics of Delphi is that you must explicitly assign a compatible type, especially between an `Integer` and a `String`. Your global variable is named `Globalstring` but yet it's declared as an `Integer`. Therefore, when you try to assign this integer to the edit control's text property, it won't compile because the types don't match.

A simple call to `IntToStr` would do the trick. There are many similar functions to convert various types to other types.

```
TextInput.Text:= IntToStr(GlobalString);
```

Mind the messages. You need to understand the errors, warnings, and hints that the compiler gives you. It's standard practice to make sure there are none. Of course the errors obviously need to be taken care of before you can even get a compiled application in the first place.

You do however have a major flaw in your design. You shouldn't be declaring an `Integer` with a name that refers to a `String`. This will only lead to future issues with maintenance. You should always declare variables with descriptive names so that you (and others) can understand what's what.

Comment: This is true but it doesn't get at the nub of the question that was asked. You've described how to fix the code in the Q, but that code was clearly fake anyway. Asker wants to know about a subsequent assignment. You can't answer that because the code is fake, and the subsequent assignment is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your form in unit4 is created when your application starts, hence `lblWelkom.Text` will be assigned a blank value since `Unit1.UserLogin` is not getting a value until the end of your `TForm1.btnLoginClick`.

Minimal change to make this work is to set `lblWelkom.Text` in the `OnShow` event instead.
Also define the global `UserLogin` before calling `Form4.Show`.

Normally you should avoid using global values. Your Form4 could have a property UserName instead, which you set before calling `Show`.

```
TForm4 =
...
private
  FUserName: String;
public
  property UserName : String read FUserName write FUserName;
...
end;
```

And in your `OnShow` event:

```
procedure TForm4.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lblWelkom.Text := UserName;
end;
```